# Read and write string to virtual file system using Emscripten

Tags: emscripten

I have a C++ program that takes two files as input and produces a file as output. These files contain strings. I successfully compiled this program to webassembly using Emscripten with the following flags:

```
emcc program.bc -o program.js -s USE_ZLIB=1 -s EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS="['FS', 'callMain']" -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -s ENVIRONMENT='web, worker'
```

I then use the following glue code to write strings (passed as parameters) to files in the Emscripten virtual file system. These files are then used to run the main function of `program`. Then the output file is read from the file system and its contents logged to console:

```js
const Module = require('./program.js')

async function main(input1, input2){
    Module.FS.writeFile('first_input.txt', input1)
    Module.FS.writeFile('second_input.txt', input2)
    Module.callMain(['-r', 'first_input.txt', '-q', 'second_input.txt', '-o', 'test.out', '-t', '1'])
    const output = Module.FS.readFile('test.out', { encoding: 'utf8' })
    console.log(output)
}

module.exports = main
```

When try to call the above main function, I get the error:

`Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'writeFile')`

When I `console.log(Module.FS)`, it is indeed undefined. Furthermore, `console.log(Module)` returns `{}`, an empty object. Inside `program.js`, the FS module does seem to be enabled, via `Module["FS"] = FS`. And when I compile this for the node environment (using `-s ENVIRONMENT='node'`) it works without a hitch.

Why is it failing for the worker environment and what can I do to fix it?

EDIT: I tried wrapping the code in the `onRuntimeInitialized' function but I'm getting the same error:

```js
const Module = require('./program.js')

async function main(input1, input2){
    Module.onRuntimeInitialized = () => {
      Module.FS.writeFile('first_input.txt', input1)
      Module.FS.writeFile('second_input.txt', input2)
      Module.callMain(['-r', 'first_input.txt', '-q', 'second_input.txt', '-o', 'test.out', '-t', '1'])
      const output = Module.FS.readFile('test.out', { encoding: 'utf8' })
      console.log(output)
    }
    
    await Module.onRuntimeInitialized()

}

module.exports = main
```

EDIT2: The above main function is actually running on a worker, not inside of a script tag in the HTML document. I cannot directly edit the HTML document, which is why I `require` the Emscripten output JavaScript file.

Comment: browser and node behave in different manner. You get the undefined Module because it's not fully initialized. You should wrap the code in a onRuntimeInitialized as described in this faq article https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/FAQ.html#how-can-i-tell-when-the-page-is-fully-loaded-and-it-is-safe-to-call-compiled-functions

Comment: And you should also provide an ajax(Promise) function for the reading files. For a example read this code: https://github.com/kalwalt/Emscripten-JpegReader/blob/9539ca68adf2b41a2cac6c3c3face1899d558c17/src/JpegReader.js#L42-L76

Comment: @kalwalt could you please elaborate on wrapping the code (preferably as an answer)? I checked the linked docs but I'm still a bit confused as to how I should modify my code. I tried wrapping the code inside the above main function (see edit) but it's giving me the same error.

Comment: No your code is not correct. It should invoked before all. i will post a detailed answer when i can. I have no time right now, sorry!

Comment: @kalwalt One thing to note, I cannot edit the html directly, so I can't add a <script> as shown the example in the docs. Actually the above main function is running on a worker not inside of a script tag. I have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to:

1. Compile the program with the `MODULARIZE=1` flag

```
emcc program.bc -o program.js -s USE_ZLIB=1 -s EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS="['FS', 'callMain']" -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -s MODULARIZE=1 -s EXPORT_NAME='createModule'
```

2. Import the module and then await the resulting promise

```js
import createModule from './program.js'

async function main(input1, input2){
    const Module = await createModule()
    Module.FS.writeFile('first_input.txt', input1)
    Module.FS.writeFile('second_input.txt', input2)
    Module.callMain(['-r', 'first_input.txt', '-q', 'second_input.txt', '-o', 'test.out', '-t', '1'])
    const output = Module.FS.readFile('test.out', { encoding: 'utf8' })
    console.log(output)
}


export default main
```

Comment: Glad that you solved, maybe the easiest one.